# Loading data into List using store Sencha Touch 2 and don't appear

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I was follow de example posted here about Loading data into List using store Sencha Touch 2 and it seems to work but when I try to do the same don't show me anything

I'm new in sencha touch and I don't know a lot about it
Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is the code:

Main:

```
var blogsStore = Ext.create("GS.store.blogs"); //put this in the items list
Ext.define('GS.view.Main',{
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype:'blog',
requires:[
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'GS.store.blogs',
    'GS.model.BlogModel'
],
config: {
    title:'Blog',
    iconCls:'star',
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'list',
            itemTpl:'{title}',
            title:'Recent Posts',
            store: blogsStore //Store instance here. And items are in array, not Object
         }
     ]

}
});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('GS.model.BlogModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'title', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'author', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'content', type: 'auto' }

    ]
}
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('GS.store.blogs',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'GS.model.BlogModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
],
config:{
     model:'GS.model.BlogModel',
    autoLoad :true,
proxy:{
            type:'jsonp',
            url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'responseData.feed.entries'
            }
        }
}
});
```

app.js:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'GS',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: [
    'Main'
],

stores: [
    'blogs'
],

models:[
    'BlogModel'
],

icon: {
    '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

isIconPrecomposed: true,

startupImage: {
    '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
    '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
    '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
    '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
    '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
    '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
},

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('GS.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error
At time of declaring the rootProperty I try to access to 'entries' element in the json returned but this property doesn't exist
Then you should modify the rootProperty:

```
rootProperty:'responseData.feed'
```

and now the app work rigth